# Android NDK r11c clang toolchain with precompiled header issue

Tags: android, android-ndk, clang

I just updated my NDK to the latest r11c and got this issue while compiling the PCH

```
clang++: error: treating 'c-header' input as 'c++-header' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated
```

I have specified my pre-compiled header file via `LOCAL_PCH` variable and the make script was going to `compile` it into a `.pch` file. But it seems clang denied this compile because of the suffix of this file is `.h`

How can I fix my `Android.mk` file to the PCH works with the r11c NDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I just change the suffix of my precompiled header files from `.h` to `.hpp` and this issue is solved.